# Preventing reentrancy and enforcing consistent state

Tags: api, sdk, consistency, reentrancy

So let's say I have a C API that looks like this:

```
// configure various parameters
int set_option(const char* name, const char* value);

// callback invoked during long running operation
typedef int (*callback_t)(void* whatever);

// start a long running operation
int some_long_operation(callback_t callback);
```

These functions are documented as not being reentrant.  Should I attempt to enforce this (e.g. by setting a flag somewhere and returning an appropriate error code) or should I just write if off as undefined behavior?  Most of the code I've seen does not attempt to do this; I'm just wondering if that's a conscious decision or if it's just pragmatism (or perhaps laziness).  It seems to me that if you wanted to write really robust code you might try something like this; on the other hand, if you're not following the documentation then maybe all bets should be off.

As a member of a team responsible for maintaining a SDK, my experience has been scary at times.  Granted our documentation is not great, but I have seen some pretty strange things in OEM support requests.  A good number of those stem from calling functions in the context of a callback invoked by another function.  Most of these are documented as being not supported, but we don't have any code in place to prevent it; in fact, most instances of this will appear to work but some may actually trash our internal state.  It just seems like sometimes it might be easier to enforce proper API usage rather than rely on people to read the documentation.

Comment: When you say reentrancy, do you also include thread safety (ie. this function is not thread safe) into this or is it a separate issue on top of reentrancy?

Comment: For the purposes of this question I am only concerned with reentrancy, though I imagine thread safety could be handled in a similar manner.